# How to get the last element in Selenium IDE thats always changing

Tags: xpath, selenium

In the code:

```
<img style="cursor: pointer; background-color: transparent;" onclick="changeTeamHint(2155);" src="/images/icon_edit_inactive.png">
```

`onclick="changeTeamHint(2155);"` is always changing. The number increases as I add more fields to my form.

How do I get the last element in Selenium IDE? For example, if I add a text field with `"changeTeamHint(2156)"`, how do I use Selenium IDE to select the latest one? If its 2157, it selects 2157. Etc.

Here's what I got so far: `xpath=(//img[@style='cursor:pointer;'])[last()]`

But my coworker told me to try to find it by onclick, and here's what I got that works: `xpath=(//img[@onclick='changeTeamHint(2155);'])[last()]`

I tried: `xpath=(//img[@onclick='changeTeamHint();'])[last()]`, but it gives me an error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want to do a starts-with for value of the onclick attribute:

```
xpath=(//img[starts-with(@onclick, 'changeTeamHint')])[last()]
```

Comment: Thank you! It helped me a lot. I tried looking for this for hours on Google, but didn't find the answer.

Comment: The [xpath document](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) is hard to read, but I find it at least lists all the methods. Then knowing the method you want, it makes it easier to Google for examples.